# Ansible puts garbage in variable when using pause

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When I try to setup a pause to prompt for a variable if this one is not set I get garbage on the variable (whether the prompt is triggered or not).

For example:

```
- pause:
  prompt: "Enter the directory of installation"
when: docroot is undefined
register: docroot
```

And I get that in the variable:

```
'{'\''skip_reason'\'': '\''Conditional result was False'\'', '\''skipped'\'': True, '\''changed'\'': False}'
```

Even if the prompt is not triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of the [docs for the pause module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pause_module.html).

Most modules return a dictionary of values, providing various details about what happened when the module ran. Therefore you cannot simply register a variable and expect it to contain the user input. Try this:

```
- block:      
    - pause:
        prompt: "Enter the directory of installation"
      register: prompt_data
    - set_fact:
        docroot: "{{ prompt_data.user_input }}"
  when: docroot is undefined
```